# Cucumber sends emails when perform_deliveries = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, cucumber

In test.rb I have:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

However, when I run my cucumber tests, they still send out emails. What configuration do I need to use to avoid this?

Comment: what rails environment are you running the cucumber tests in?

Comment: I assumed test environment. In the terminal I type 'cucumber'. Do I need to specify the test environment somewhere?

Comment: If you have set it up correctly, then no

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was pushing jobs to sidekiq, and I guess it sidekiq doesn't respect the environment settings.

For rspec, in spec_helper.rb, I had:

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
```

I had to implement the same code in env.rb for cucumber.